# How to connect to a database from outside of a web app?

Tags: java, jpa

I am developing a java web app with Wicket (with jpa). Inside the Wicket Application i can access the database Persistence Unit with Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory() configured in persistence.xml.

Now i want to have a helper script to perform maintenance tasks. I created a java file with a `static void main` method but if i run this file, I get an Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method 
that is not native or abstract in class file javax/persistence/Persistence
```

In the test files, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have JPA on your classpath.

Depending on your JPA provider, this will be at least `javax.persistence-*-.jar` plus the provider-specific JARs, e.g. `eclipselink-x.y.z.jar` or a bunch of JARs for Hibernate. Check out what lives in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder if you're not sure.

Comment: If i add the folder, where all these files are, to my CLASSPATH system variable, it does not work.

Comment: Don't mess with your system variables, list the JARs individually when invoking java, e.g. `java -cp one.jar;two.jar;three.jar mypackage.MyClass` (`;` is path separator on Windows, use `:` on Linux). You might want to put that command line into a batch/bash script. If you still have problems, please add the exact command you invoke to your question and I'll have a look.